# Unmute Notification sound/ vibration while running a recording AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, avaudiosession

While running an `AVAudioSession` configured with `.playAndRecord` or `.record` category the system will mute sound & vibration of any (Push)Notification received by the phone.

-> If one app is running a recording session in fore- or background notifications for **all** apps will be muted.

That might be a reasonable setup in most cases but I'm looking for a workaround to unmute notifications while recording audio: Is there any way to

- setup an iPhone to play notification sounds/ vibrations while a recording session is running in an app?
- configure the recording `AVAudioSession` of my app to enable interruptions by notifications and hence unmute them?
- configure a (local) `UNNotification` to interrupt a recording session when it is fired? I noticed that the "Timer" notifications sent by the iPhones "Clock" App do have this ability (invoke `AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification` notifications). Wondering if there is something I missed when configuring the notification or if Apple is using private API to do so.